# closed form for a series over the Riemann zeta zeros

Tags: number-theory, power-series, riemann-zeta

given the series $ \sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{z-\rho} $ here the sum is taken OVER the roots of the Riemann function on the critical line $ 0 < Re(s) <1 $

the summation is understood as we sum the pair of zeros $ f( \rho) +f(1-\rho ) $ so $ Re (\rho) > 0 $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may start with the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Hadamard_product) :
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac{e^{s\left(\log(2\pi)-1-\frac{\gamma}2\right)}}{2(s-1)\Gamma\left(1+\frac s2\right)}\prod_{\rho} \left(1-\frac s{\rho}\right) e^{s/{\rho}}
$$
or use the Riemann [Xi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function) $\xi(s)=\frac 12 s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma\left(\frac s2\right)\zeta(s)$
to rewrite this as a 
$$\xi(s)=\xi(0)\prod_{\rho} 1-\frac s{\rho}$$

so that $\displaystyle \dfrac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)} = \sum^\prime_{\rho} \left(\ln\left(1-\frac s{\rho}\right)\right)' = \sum^\prime_{\rho} \frac 1{s-\rho}$
at least if I did'nt make a stupid mistake... (the ' over the sum meaning your summation convention)

---

You also may find the following derivation interesting:
$$\xi(s)=\xi(0)e^{B s}\prod_{\rho} \left(1-\frac s{\rho}\right) e^{s/{\rho}}$$
with $B=\log 2+\frac 12 \log\pi-1-\frac{\gamma}2$ and $\rho$ the non-trivial zeros.

so that $\displaystyle \dfrac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)} = B+\sum_{\rho} \left(\ln\left(1-\frac s{\rho}\right)e^{s/{\rho}}\right)' = B+ \sum^\prime_{\rho} \frac 1{s-\rho} + \frac 1{\rho}$

There is no contradiction thanks to $\displaystyle B=-\sum^\prime_{\rho} \frac 1{\rho}=-\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0} \frac 1{\rho(1-\rho)}$

For more see Edwards' [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=IpZjL5_EsI8C&pg=PA20),
Coffey's ['Toward verification of the Riemann hypothesis: Application of the Li criterion'](http://arXiv.org/abs/math-ph/0505052v1)
the MO article ['Is this sum of reciprocals of zeta zeros correct?'](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91280/is-this-sum-of-reciprocals-of-zeta-zeros-correct)
and Lagarias' paper ['The Riemann Hypothesis: Arithmetic and 
Geometry'](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/mt-holyoke-rev.pdf)

Comment: thanks all the people, who answered, of course if i put $ 1/2+iz $ with 'z' complex  i can evaluate the sum only over the imaginary parts $ \sum_{n} (is-it_{n})^{-1} $

Comment: I see only one answer (maybe written by more than one person, who knows :-), but this one's a good one: +1.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @draks !

Comment: [Sketch of a derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2863308/21783) using the first expression.