# Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: riemann-zeta

Can somebody provide me with the formula for the sum of reciprocal of the roots of the Riemann zeta function?

Also if $a+ib$ is a root, will $a-ib$ also be a root?

Comment: We should have :
$$\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho (1{-}\rho)}=\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{|\rho|^2} = 2 + \gamma - \log 4\pi$$
see [Is this sum of reciprocals of zeta zeros correct?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91280/is-this-sum-of-reciprocals-of-zeta-zeros-correct) or [closed form for a series over the Riemann zeta zeros](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/closed-form-for-a-series-over-the-riemann-zeta-zeros).

Comment: By the way, @RaymondManzoni I was really hoping to get the very first (riemann-zeta) tag badge ever on the site. Congrats on dashing my hopes!

Comment: @anon: In fact I thought that Eric and you both had it (I had forgotten the minimal $20$ limit) so that I felt a little alone :-). Note that I am kind here and let you all the points (and count) (of course you got my vote !). Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lemma: If $f(z)$ is an analytic power series with real coefficients, then $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}$ for all $z\in{\bf C}$.

Try to prove this. Generalize to meromorphic $f$. Alternatively, $n^{-\bar{s}}=\overline{n^{-s}}$. Thus $\zeta(\bar{s})=\overline{\zeta(s)}$, so nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function come in conjugate pairs $\{\rho,\overline{\rho}\}$.

The sum of reciprocals of nontrivial zeros of the zeta function is given by

$$\sum_\rho\frac{1}{\rho}=1+\frac{1}{2}\gamma-\frac{1}{2}\log(4\pi)$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). This is unconditional on the truth of the Riemann hypothesis, but the sum is not absolutely convergent (the summands must be paired as conjugates in order to attain convergence). The sums $\sum_\rho\rho^{-k}$ for some other $k$ are also known.

See equations & discussion in $(3)$ through $(11)$ on [MathWorld's article on $\zeta(s)$'s zeros](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeros.html).

Comment: in order to attain **absolute** convergence, for each the pair $1/\rho + 1/\bar{\rho} = 2 | Re(1/\rho) |$ so that simple convergence implies absolute convergence.