# Sum over all inverse zeta nontrivial zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Starting from the Hadamard product for the Riemann Zeta Function (assuming the product is taken over matching pairs of zeros)
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{e^{(\log(2\pi)-1-\gamma/2)s}}{2(s-1)\Gamma(1+s/2)}\prod_{\rho}\left(1-\frac{s}{\rho} \right)e^{s/\rho}$$
can one derive the exact value of $\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho}$
to be
$$\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho} = -\log(2\sqrt{\pi})+1+\gamma/2$$
What implications does this have?

Comment: Basically none. Also note the sum doesn't converge absolutely.

Comment: $$-\log \left(2 \sqrt{\pi }\right)+1+\frac{\gamma }{2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\lim_{s\to 0} \, \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\zeta (s) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (2 s-1)}+\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (s-1)}\right)+\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right) \zeta (s)\right)-\lim_{s\to 1} \, \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\zeta (s) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (2 s-1)}+\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (s-1)}\right)+\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right) \zeta (s)\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the logarithm of the Hadamard product and take the derivative relatively to $s$ (remembering that $\;\psi(z):=\dfrac d{dz}\log\Gamma(z)\,$ with [$\psi$ the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)) :
\begin{align}
\log\zeta(s)&=(\log(2\pi)-1-\gamma/2)s-\log\left(2(s-1)\Gamma(1+s/2)\right)+\sum_{\rho}\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\rho} \right)+\frac s{\rho}\\
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}&=\log(2\pi)-1-\gamma/2-\left(\frac 1{s-1}+\frac 12\psi\left(\frac s2+1\right)\right)+\sum_{\rho}\frac 1{s-\rho}+\frac 1{\rho}\\
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac 1{s-1}&=\log(2\pi)-1-\gamma/2-\frac 12\psi\left(\frac s2+1\right)+\sum_{\rho}\frac 1{s-\rho}+\frac 1{\rho}\\
\end{align}
taking the limit as $s\to 1$ and [remembering that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) $\;\displaystyle \zeta(s)-\frac 1{s-1}=\gamma+O(s-1)\;$ [and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Special_values) $\psi\left(\frac 32\right)=\psi\left(\frac 12\right)+2=-\gamma-\log(4)+2\;$ we get :
\begin{align}
\gamma&=\log(2\pi)-1-\gamma/2+\left(\gamma/2+\log(2)-1\right)+\sum_{\rho}\frac 1{1-\rho}+\frac 1{\rho}\\
\sum_{\rho}\frac 1{1-\rho}+\frac 1{\rho}&=-\log(4\pi)+2+\gamma
\end{align}
With the answer the double of your series (as it should since if $\rho$ is a root then $1-\rho$ will also be one).

I considered here only a formal derivation (the series is only conditionally convergent : the roots must be sorted with increasing absolute imaginary parts, the limit inside the series should be justified) ; for detailed proofs see for example [Edwards' book p.67](https://books.google.com/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA67).

For the sum of integer powers of the roots see [Mathworld starting at $(5)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeros.html).

Other references were proposed in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/closed-form-for-a-series-over-the-riemann-zeta-zeros/131761) as this [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91280/is-this-sum-of-reciprocals-of-zeta-zeros-correct) that may be more useful for your question concerning 'implications' (see the answer and comment to Micah Milinovich).