# Infinite sum of powerseries likely converges to a powerseries with rational coefficients and has then a simple generating function... proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, fixed-points, tetration

***Background:*** In a discussion in the "*[tetration-forum](https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1203&pid=9490#pid9490)*" a term $\log(x-L)/L+\log(x-L^*)/L^*$ occured, where $L$ and $L^*$ mean the (complex) primary fixpoint (and its conjugate) of the $\exp()$-function. Because the conjugate values occur symmetrically in the sum of the two formal powerseries, the result is a formal powerseries with real coefficients, and we could as well write $T(x) = 2 \cdot \Re (\log(x - L)/L) $ where $\Re()$ means the real part of its argument.

---

***Problem:*** Because the exponential function has infinitely many complex fixpoints I thought what would a formal powerseries $S(x)$ look like, when it is the sum off *all* such $T()$ - or: when *all* that fixpoints are taken into account?

Let's write $L_k$ for the $k$'th fixpoint, with $L_1 \approx 0.318131505205 + 1.33723570143 \, î$ , then $$T_k(x)=2 \cdot \Re (\frac {\log(x-L_k)}{L_k}) \tag 1$$ (here, using the convention of W|A, we get the $k$'th fixpoint by $\small {L_k = \exp(-\text{productlog}(-k,-1))}$).

---

Now the sum of all that $T_k(x)$ (taken as formal power series) gives another formal powerseries
$$ S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n T_k(x) = s_{n:0} + s_{n:1} x + s_{n:2} x^2 + \cdots  \tag 2 $$
where -heuristically- it seems, that for $n \to \infty$ the values of $s_{n:0}$ diverges but all other coefficients $s_{n:k}$ converge to a finite value, and moreover, to *rational* values.

***Heuristics:*** Here are the leading coefficients for some $S_n(x)$ up to $n=2^{16}-1$

```
  n    s_{n:0}          s_{n:1}          s_{n:2}          s_{n:3}        s_{n:4}            ....
  -------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------
    1  -2.44695072007  0.945130773416  0.248253690529  -0.111008639310  -0.0937330420633
    3  -2.93357528303  0.982250645218  0.249909831374  -0.111105628916  -0.0937498749582
    7  -3.29668141804  0.992566300100  0.249991660549  -0.111110673480  -0.0937499978358
   15  -3.63438202949  0.996574875354  0.249999033336  -0.111111067412  -0.0937499999458
   31  -3.96777440601  0.998353868014  0.249999876694  -0.111111106232  -0.0937499999984
   63  -4.30277816467  0.999192862471  0.249999983621  -0.111111110535  -0.0937499999999
  127  -4.64069484715  0.999600341105  0.249999997790  -0.111111111041  -0.0937500000000
  255  -4.98130134424  0.999801140528  0.249999999701  -0.111111111102  -0.0937500000000
  511  -5.32397016248  0.999900812031  0.249999999960  -0.111111111110  -0.0937500000000
 1023  -5.66808038151  0.999950466396  0.249999999995  -0.111111111111  -0.0937500000000
 2047  -6.01314198265  0.999975248290  0.249999999999  -0.111111111111  -0.0937500000000
 4095  -6.35880718549  0.999987627918  0.250000000000  -0.111111111111  -0.0937500000000
 8191  -6.70484432699  0.999993814902  0.250000000000  -0.111111111111  -0.0937500000000
16383  -7.05110555754  0.999996907687  0.250000000000  -0.111111111111  -0.0937500000000
32767  -7.39749940344  0.999998453902  0.250000000000  -0.111111111111  -0.0937500000000
65535  -7.74397059311  0.999999226966  0.250000000000  -0.111111111111  -0.0937500000000
   ....
```

***Conjecture 1:*** coefficients $s_{n:k}$ are *rational* in the limit for $n \to \infty$      (except for $s_{n:0}$ which diverges to $-\infty$)

If we assume, that indeed that coefficients converge to rational values, we can arrive at a sequence of integer coefficients by a very simple rational scaling:

$$\begin{array} {} \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x)= S(x)&=  s_0 &+ 1\cdot x + 1\cdot \frac{x^2}{2!}\frac12 − 2\cdot \frac{x^3}{3!}\frac13 − 9\cdot \frac{x^4}{4!}\frac14 \\ && + 6\cdot \frac{x^5}{5!}\frac15  + 155\cdot \frac{x^6}{6!}\frac16  + 232\cdot \frac{x^7}{7!}\frac17 + ... \end{array} \tag 3$$

***Coefficients seem to be known:***
The miraculous database of integer-sequences, [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A009306), knows this coefficients $[1,1,-2,-9,6,155,232, \ldots]$ saying they have the exponential generating function (which I modify here slightly for my purposes):
$$ \begin{array} {} U(x) = \frac{\log(1- x\exp(-x))}x  &= -1 &+ 1\cdot x\frac12 + 1\cdot \frac{x^2}{2!}\frac13 − 2\cdot \frac{x^3}{3!}\frac14 − 9\cdot \frac{x^4}{4!}\frac15 \\ &&+ 6\cdot \frac{x^5}{5!}\frac16 +  155\cdot \frac{x^6}{6!}\frac17 + ... \end{array} \tag 4$$

Here the coefficient at the constant term is $u_0=-1$ and is likely different to the value of $s_0$ which is a result of a likely divergent series.

I've a simple modification of the $U()$-function which matches then the conjectured rational coefficients of $S(x)$ even by the indexes:

$$ U_1(x)={\small{\exp(x)-1 \over \exp(x)-x} }\tag {5.a} $$
$$ U_2(x) = \int { \small{\frac{U_1(x)}x}} dx + s_0 \tag {5.b}
$$
$\qquad \qquad $  <sub>$U_1$ is a reformulation of the derivative of $U(x)$ and $U_2(x)$ a termwise integration</sub>

Then Pari/GP gives me the following powerseries:

```
U_2(x)= s0 + x + 1/4*x^2 - 1/9*x^3 - 3/32*x^4 + 1/100*x^5 + 31/864*x^6 + 29/4410*x^7 - 63/5120*x^8 - 2087/326592*x^9 + 39593/12096000*x^10 + 45973/12196800*x^11 - 146387/522547200*x^12 - 10264123/5782233600*x^13 - 2678759/6258954240*x^14 + 833302651/1225944720000*x^15 + 46063312597/111588212736000*x^16 + O(x^17)
```

***Conjecture 2:*** The coefficients of the limiting formal powerseries of $S(x)$ are the same as that of $U_2(x)$

This seems to be a nice coincidence - if the assumption *(conjecture 1)* of convergence of the coefficients in $S(x)$ to that rational values holds. I chewed a bit on how to approach a proof, but didn't have a promising idea yet.

> Q1: how could this apparent coincidence of the limit of the sum-of-powerseries in $S(x)$ with the coefficients in $U(x)$ *(or better $U_2(x)$)* be proved?
> Q2: can the value of $s_0$ be expressed by a regularized summation?

Comment: The directly relevant posting is https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1203&pid=8889#pid8889

Comment: Thank you for posting such questions. Unfortunately Im not as skilled as the people at the tetration forum or the better ones here. But when I have time I might look into it. Congrats with $10 \pi k$ reputation :)

Comment: Have you tried contour integration ? keyhole integration ? residue theorems ? Those kind ?

Comment: I believe $L_k$ can be approximated with elementary functions like arccosh or such ...

Comment: LambertW functions might help you out ?

Comment: @mick - ehmmm, I use the LambertW for the computation of the fixpoints already (the version of Mike3 in the tetration-forum). Or what do you mean? *(I've nowhere seen so far a discussion of something like "sum-of-all-fixpoints has rational value" or as in this question "sum-of-all $T_k(x)$ has rational value", but maybe simply have missing such a discussion elsewhere)*

Comment: Im not sure but I know there exists math for sums of functions taken over the zero's of other functions. 
See for instance at the second half of this :
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeros.html

Comment: @mick - thanks for the link, nice compilation there! I've met infinite sums involving roots from time to time, but never delved into it deeper. I'll be happy if this here shall have any significance for J.D.Fox' analysis (in the tetration-forum) of his slog()-powerseries who used only the sum with one single fixpoint: it seems the powerseries $\text{res}(x)=\text{slog}(x)-S(x)$ might be entire... and $\text{slog}(x)=\text{res}(x)+S(x) = \text{res}(x) + U_2(x)$ might then be evaluable to higher precision...

Comment: you meant $res(x) = slog(x) - U(x)$ ? because $s_0$ is infinite !?
Why would that function $res(z)$ be entire ? Can you show $res(z)$ to have full domain ( reach every complex value ) ?

Comment: Also for what type of slog ? all of them ? Or kneser ? tommy 2sinh ? or ??

Comment: also not sure why you edited to take the derivative and integrate again.

Comment: as for $res(z)$ being entire , should it not be a riemann surface like a log thing ? And what happens with the higher order fixpoints ??

Comment: A link would be nice to where this was discussed at the forum btw

Comment: probably useful : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862563/sum-over-all-inverse-zeta-nontrivial-zeros

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/closed-form-for-a-series-over-the-riemann-zeta-zeros/131761

I think it should be possible to find the infinite product expansion of exp(z) - z and retrieve therefore a similar method.

This product expansion occurs very often in complex analysis and it has even been seen in the topic " fake function theory " on the tetration forum.

Comment: hmm is $res(z)$ is entire it should have a similar product form. That would be surprising since that might mean it grows exponential or faster ... unless it is determined by its zero's only.

Comment: @Mick - hi mick, thanks for your engagement. I made an error - usually I check the hypothese of "entireness" on base of increasing ratio of consecutive coefficients of the taylor series. Don't know what I did wrong the day I'd written this: recalculation doesn't support such hypothese: "entireness" no more conjectured! --- The link to the tetration-forum is in the beginning of the post.

Comment: @Mick - concerning your question: "which method?" The thread in the tetration-forum is, even in the subject line, about Jay D. Fox' numerically improvement of P. Walkers and A.Robbins' "matrix-method". No "Kneser" et.al. involved. But because the convergence to a series with *rational* coefficients is a complete separate topic, I didn't refer to any tetration-method at all: they are only the background/motivation of the consideration of such a sum-of-formal-powerseries: simply a stand-alone project.